# How do you annotate instantiation in UML class diagrams?

Tags: uml, object-oriented-design, class-diagram

Given this pseudo code:

```
class B { }

class A : B
{
    int val;
};

alpha = new A();
```

What arrow do I draw between `alpha` and `A` in a UML class diagram? Is this even something UML is meant to do?

```
+-------+        +-------+        +-------+
| alpha | --??-- |   A   |------|>|   B   |
|       |        |       |        |       |
+-------+        +-------+        +-------+
```

In my case, I truly do want to express explicitly that `alpha` instantiates `A`. So if there is no way in UML, I'll just make up a way -- which is fine, but I want to know if UML can express it already. My situation is that I'm trying to explain OOP to a friend who is very visual. Therefore, I want to try to visually distinguish the two relationships (inheritance and instantiation) so that he can distinguish it mentally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a class diagram, you don't show the act of instantiation. That is something that a sequence or communication diagram would show. Class diagrams show the static structure of a system.

If a class A "depends on" a class B, then you could look at the association and dependency relationships. [Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Dependency) is the weaker of the two and is usually used if the other class is a parameter to a method and is not stored as an instance variable. [Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Association) is stronger and means that class A contains an instance (or instances) of class B, and is further strengthened by the composition and aggregation relations.

In your example, `alpha` isn't part of a class. If `alpha` was an instance variable in some class `C`, you would connect `C` to `A` with an association. If it was a parameter to a method or created inside a method of `C` and not stored as an instance variable, you would use a dependency line to connect `C` to `A`. In all cases, you have the ability to specify directionality and multiplicity.

I think a larger problem is that you appear to be associating UML with "class diagram". The UML 2.2 specification has 14 diagram types. There are 7 structural diagrams, and 7 behavioral diagrams (broken down into 3 behavior diagrams and 4 interaction diagrams). Each diagram shows a particular view of the system. Some aspects of the system are best shown using a particular diagram, or in some cases, a series of diagrams. If you are interested, I would recommend checking out [Wikipedia's entry on UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) and [Martin Fowler's UML Distilled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020165783X). Both give great overviews of the purpose, strengths, and weaknesses of various diagram types.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Thomas Owens that class diagrams in UML are not meant to show instances in general. However, I must add that UML does provide mechanisms to depict instantiation:

- the InstanceSpecification element provides a way to model instances, such as `alpha` in your example.
- the dependency notation (a dashed arrow with plain arrowhead), flowing from the instance to its type, and adorned with the stereotype `<<instanceOf>>`, provides a way to model the instantiation relationship between an instance and its classifier(s).

Comment: Are you referring to what is discussed on http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html#dependency? I've never seen the instanceOf stereotype, but I have seen <<creates>> and <<uses>> before.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: Well, <<instanceOf>> is a well known stereotype since the earliest versions of UML. If you look at the latest stable spec (http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/) of the UML infrastructure, you'll find multiple examples of its usage, such as the classical Figure 7.8 about the four-layer metamodel hierarchy that has been used ad nauseam in a multitude of publications.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to poke around. Although I'm familiar with UML, I've never dug into the formal spec and all of it's little intricies before.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: Sure, and good luck. :-)

Comment: To add a reference:  http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-core.html#instance-specification-core

Answer (score 4):

[image]

There is a special stereotype for such dependency. Class INSTANTIATES Class2, if it creates its instances. Exists in UML standard. ( I checked 2.4.1 - contemporary and 2.5 - the next one.)